# Haskell Constructor Type Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell

I have a simple type and function below, but seems a lot of boilerplate there, so wonder is there a better way to do it. My real question I guess is if I know the input is of type Ability, so any one of the Str/Dex etc, what is the easiest way to extract the Integer from it without pattern match each one of them?

```
data Ability = StrAbi Integer
         | DexAbi Integer
         | ConAbi Integer
         | IntAbi Integer
         | WisAbi Integer
         | ChaAbi Integer
         deriving (Show)

data Modifier = Modifier Integer deriving (Show)

setModifier :: Ability -> (Ability, Modifier)
setModifier abi@(StrAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
setModifier abi@(DexAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
setModifier abi@(ConAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
setModifier abi@(IntAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
setModifier abi@(WisAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
setModifier abi@(ChaAbi s) = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' s)
```

Thanks,
//

Comment: You could also derive `Functor`.

Comment: so you mean to map over the Ability type?

Comment: Another option is `where m = modifier' s`. at the end of the block.  Combine it with `where a = ability' s` and at least you move the boilerplate into utility functions that only need to be written once.

Comment: @pip https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DeriveFunctor and then write `setModifier` with `fmap`. Or derive lenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you have a datastructure where each possible constructor has a fields that has the same semantical meaning, you can use *record syntax*, and thus give that child a name:

```
data Ability = StrAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         | DexAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         | ConAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         | IntAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         | WisAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         | ChaAbi { abilityValue :: Integer }
         deriving (Show)
```

The nice thing is, you *automatically* have constructed a function `abilityValue :: Ability -> Integer` that thus has access to that field.

Next we can simply write:

```
setModifier :: Ability -> (Ability, Modifier)
setModifier abi = (abi, Modifier $ modifier' $ abilityValue abi)
```

There is of course some effort in *specifying* the name of the fields, but if these values have a "similar semantical meaning", then it will usually pay off since you have introduced a "getter" (and you can use record notation for "setters").

Comment: maybe off topic, is Lens has anything related to this? I am asking because you mentioned getter/setter. I like your answer alot

Answer (score 13):

Can you refactor the datatype?

```
data Ability = Ability { abilityType :: AbilityType, abilityValue :: Integer }
data AbilityType = Str | Dec | Con | Int | Wis | Cha
```

`setModifier` would have the same definition as Willem Van Onsem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For some reason I was avoiding record syntax for this, but I should for sure re-evaluate this.

Comment: The key improvement here is not record syntax at all, but factoring out the many duplicate Integer fields in different constructors to all be inside the same constructor with another field indicating the AbilityType.

Comment: To wit: without record syntax, `data Ability = Ability AbilityType Integer` and `setModifier a@(Ability _ v) = (a, Modifier $ modifier' v)` is already worlds better than your original.

Comment: daniel - your answer crossed my mind but the pattern matching with _ gave me issue. i'll try again, and that is the apporach i want. thx

Answer (score 2):

Answering the comment-question about using Lens (with MicroLens-platform in this answer but for these operations its the exact same code as full Lens with smaller dependencies):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Lens.Micro.Platform
data Ability
         = StrAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         | DexAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         | ConAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         | IntAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         | WisAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         | ChaAbi { _abilityValue :: Integer }
         deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Ability

-- Just some examples
getAbilityValue :: Ability -> Integer
getAbilityValue ab = ab ^. abilityValue

setAbilityValue :: Ability -> Integer -> Ability
setAbilityValue ab val = ab & abilityValue .~ val

modifyAbilityValue :: Ability -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Ability
modifyAbilityValue ab f = ab & abilityValue %~ f

-- Edit after reading the question instead of just the comment:
data Modifier = Modifier Integer deriving (Show)

setModifier :: Ability -> (Ability, Modifier)
setModifier ab = (ab,Modifier (ab ^. abilityValue))
-- or import Control.Arrow and
-- setModifier = id &&& Modifier . (^. abilityValue)
```